# Controlling direction of current flow through pin depending on the type of device connected

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, connector, bidirectional, reverse-polarity

I have a small portable device - lets call it MASTER - which can be inserted into two different accessories - CHARGER and SLAVE. You can check very rough block diagrams in the attached picture.

[image: diagram]

MASTER has 40mAh LiPo battery inside with nominal voltage around 3.7V (but of course during usage it's something between 3 and 4.2V). This voltage is further regulated to 1.8V. That is the voltage that is used by MCU.

MASTER has 3 pins/pads that extend outside the MASTER’s enclosure. They don’t extend much but user can definitely touch them or short them otherwise.

CHARGER and SLAVE have spring fingers (something like this http://www.te.com/catalog/products/en?q=2199001) that form a contact when MASTER is put inside.

DATA pin is used for single wire SLAVE/CHARGER identification. The memory with ID is parasitically powered so it can be read even when battery is not connector to the SLAVE. MASTER can easily determine if the connected accessory is SLAVE or CHARGER.

Everything else on the SLAVE (except memory) must be powered from MASTER’s BAT and GND pins because SLAVE has no battery.

But also MASTER’s battery must be rechargeable through BAT and GND pins.

Which finally gets us to the problem - **Is it possible to supply voltage to the SLAVE and also recharge MASTER’s battery using only single pin? And of course without possibility to short-circuit the MASTER’s battery and other components.**

NOTE: Supplying voltage to SLAVE and recharging MASTER will NEVER occur at the same time, these are completely separated events.

Now some ideas I had but was unable to implement (probably because I'm too stupid :)):

- You can use identification on SLAVE/CHARGER to “open” supplying/charging paths of circuit, but consider that charging the battery MUST be possible even when battery is completely drained and cut off.
- Using some MOSFET/transistor magic to recognize type of accessory (SLAVE or CHARGER).
- Cut off the BAT pin from battery when overcurrent is detected. But fast - resettable fuses are not fast enough. Also relay or SSR relay is not suitable because of its size.
- Last idea was to use 4 pins instead of just 3. This should be the last resort. If you guys tell me it cannot be done with only 3 pins, I'll ask new question.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What is the default state of the external data line on each?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The single wire interface is UNI/O by Microchip ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNI/O)). Wiki says "The idle state of the UNI/O bus is logic high."

Comment: Then you've won half of the battle already, since you can detect insertion events.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, insertion events can be detected even by polling the data line from the master. I can even find out what type (CHARGER/SLAVE) is inserted.

Comment: I wouldn't poll, I'd use a weak pulldown and connect the data line to an interrupt pin. You can then use this as a trigger to start the transistor magic (since that's how you will be doing this) after things have settled.

Comment: To continue, you'd have a couple of MOSFETs connecting the battery line, with another MOSFET on the outside of these in the ohmic region to detect when the charger is connected. The problem comes when the battery is dead, although you could take advantage of the body diode to supply power to the MCU in that case.

Comment: Could you please draw simple diagram, because one image is like thousand words :) And I'm very sorry, but my knowledge of MOSFETs is quite limited. I've used them for just simple designs.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.powerguru.org/mosfet-based-battery-protection-systems/), but you'll probably have to use a mixed pair since you need a connection to happen when the battery is dead. And then the other MOSFET goes to ground and the current through it measured, but shut off when the peripheral has been determined. I don't have enough experience to finish the circuit for you, but someone should be able to take these ramblings and turn them into something useful.

Comment: Thank you, lets hope that someone will appear and help us :) I've spent quite a lot of time on this and still nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You are making this too difficult. All you need to do is a battery switch that will disconnect BAT line when no accessories are plugged in. This is trivial to do with a single MOSFET (it will have a protection diode, so make sure you connect it such that you cannot discharge the battery when MOSFET is off). A microcontroller should open the MOSFET when device is plugged in, and then it will be virtually indistinguishable from the wire.

Your only concern left is what happens when battery runs down. Well, in this case the MOSFET's protection diode will help -- it will allow some limiting battery charging even when MOSFET is off. It will not allow full charging due to voltage drop, but it does not matter -- the moment the battery has just a bit of power, MCU will start up and open the MOSFET.

Comment: I thought about that. Did you mean it like this? [Link to image](http://i.imgur.com/gMgRRxd.png)

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention it but MCU is running on 1.8V and its outputs are therefore capable of only 1.8V. If MOSFET is used as in the picture above, I'm not able to do Vgs > Vth. Am I right?

Comment: Your image is mostly correct. A P-fet will be driven to ground, so its Vgs will be the same as battery voltage. You will need another transistor to drive it. Example: http://www.edaboard.com/thread237294.html

Comment: I did some simulation and it looks like it will work well :) Screenshot from simulation is [here](http://i.imgur.com/N0MY4Dr.png) and live simulation is [here](http://bit.ly/12gHKrn). Just switch both switches so that only one is active at the time. What do you think? I will try to build it and post results.

Comment: Ok, guys. I've build it on breadboard and it works. At least the part that cuts off the pin. But I've got another problem - charging cycle never ends when I put charger on the BAT pin and open the mosfet. Could you please at least point what could be the wrong? I'm using MCP73831T-2ACI/OT ([datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/630369.pdf)) which is outside the MASTER in the CHARGER.

Comment: Or should I post a completely new question?

Comment: I am going to randomly guess your MOSFET is not open all the way. What is the MOSFET part number? What is voltage drop across MOSFET while the battery is being charged (between SOURCE and DRAIN pins)? It should be < 0.1 volt.

Comment: Voltage drop on SOURCE and DRAIN is 0.04 volt. I'm trying second run and will try to experiment more. MOSFET is IRF9520 ([datasheet](http://www.uib.cat/depart/dfs/GTE/education/industrial/tec_analogiques/IRF9520.pdf)).

On first run charger didn't finish the charging (STAT pin was low). Battery voltage was 4.2V (it could be little less but I'm using only not-so-professional multimeter). After closing and reopening the mosfet again the charger finished charging and STAT switched to high.

Comment: Second run had same results. When battery voltage is 4.2V the voltage drop on source and drain is 0V, which means that no current is flowing into the battery, right?

Comment: I have posted new question about it. Please see [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/142355/charging-of-battery-never-ends-using-mcp73831-2aci-ot).